# Amazon S3 domain level privacy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, privacy

I have to use the Amazon S3 to store interactive video files created by Camtasia. Then I have to display these videos on a website with iframe on a specific domain, without turning these files public. It is a feature at Vimeo called domain-level privacy, which means that you can choose what specific website you want to allow your video to be embedded on.

How can I achieve it at the Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The iframe redefined the "referer", that's why the amazon blocked the sources within it.

Answer (score 1):

I've already reached the point where I can control the access of a file with the Bucket Policy this way:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://myurl.hu/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It would be fine if I call a single file in the iframe but I have to get a .html file which has links in it to other .js files from the same bucket directory. And the I get the 403 codes.

Comment: Side-note: It is possible for people to fake the `Referer`, so don't rely on this level of protection for sensitive data.